# Scala first program issue

Tags: scala, recursion, case, frequency

I have just started to learn Scala after some experience with functional programming in other languages.

```
def freq(c:Char, y:String, list:List[(Char,Int)]): List[(Char,Int)] = list match{
  case _ =>  freq(c, y.filter(_ == c), list :: List((count(c,y),c))) 
  case nil => list
}
```

In the above code I am getting an error when trying to concatenate the list recursively. The error is occurring in `list::List((count(c,y),c))`. The count method takes a char and a string and returns an int based on how many times that char occurs.

Any help would be much appreciated. The error I am getting states found [(Char,Int)] required (Char,Int).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cons operator (`::`) is an infix operator so if you want to get a type of `List[T]` and not `List[List[T]]` then you should write

```
freq(c, y.filter(_ == c),(count(c,y),c)) :: list)
```

Comment: Found (Char,Int) required List[(Char,Int)]??

Comment: In which line? BTW: `c` is of type `Char` and a tuple you're creating should have second element of type `Int` - it still will not compile.

Comment: The return type of count is an Int while c is a char.

Comment: So you should write: `freq(c, y.filter(_ == c),(c, count(c,y))) :: list)`

Comment: Like this  case _ =>  freq(c, y.filter(_ == c),(c, count(c,y)) :: list)  it compiles :P

Answer (score 0):

Also you need to switch the 2 match cases because nil would never be evaluated this way. `_` will catch nil too and never continue to reach the second case.

Comment: Thanks I will keep that in mind, it works a little different from Haskell where I can just put [] = [] or otherwise.